# HTTP GET using lwip stops part way through

Tags: http, http-get, lwip

I'm using lwip as a client to do an HTTP GET from a server. The file I'm hoping to receive is roughly 75kB. I get the first ~9kB correctly but then no more data arrives. Each packet that arrives in the stack is properly ACK'd.

To cut a long bit of code short, I'm using the netconn interface with the following commands. None give errors until several packets have arrived, after this the netconn_recv starts giving timeouts until after about 15 mins the server sends a packet to close down the connection (this tells me that the connection is still working in some sense at least).

```
#define HTTP_GET_TEMPLATE "GET /%s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n"

addr = <the ip address I'm talking to>
location = <location of the filename on the host>
host = <hostname>

upg = netconn_new(NETCONN_TCP);
netconn_set_recvtimeout(upg, 30000);
err = netconn_bind(upg, IP_ADDR_ANY, 0);
err = netconn_connect(upg, &addr, 80);
sprintf(request, HTTP_GET_TEMPLATE, location, host);
siRc = netconn_write(upg, request, (strlen(request)+1)*sizeof(char), NETCONN_COPY);
while (true)
{
    err = netconn_recv(upg, &netbuf);
    if (ERR_IS_FATAL(err))
    {
        break;
    }
    if (err == ERR_OK)
    {
        do
        {
            err = netbuf_data(netbuf, &data, &len);
            < handle the data in "data">
        } while (netbuf_next(netbuf) >= 0);

        netbuf_delete(netbuf);
    }
}
```

Can anyone give me any hints for what to try next? Thanks